# How to inherit generic virtual method?

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, delphi-xe2

I have the following code. I want to override the Notify method of the base base list on this to be able to create an event on the modification of the list.

```
  TDescendantList = class(TObjectList<TSomeclass>)
  private
    <...>
  protected
    procedure Notify(const Value: T;
      Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
    <...>
  end;
```

If I put `Value: T` I get an ***"Undeclared identifier"*** on T.

If is `Value: TSomeClass` I get the ***"Declaration of 'Notify' differs from previous declaration"***.

`Notify` is a protected method of `TObjectList<T: class>`. This method does not appear on overriding list of the XE2 IDE.

That's some way to implement this or I need to use another approach as this is an proverbial brick wall?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your descendant class is fixing the generic type then you have to use that fixed type in place of T. In your case :

```
protected
  procedure Notify(const Value: TSomeclass;
                   Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
```

is the correct way to declare this function.

---

The error :

> Declaration of 'Notify' differs from previous declaration

is a regrettable case of the Delphi RTL duplicating type names in different units.

The unit `System.Classes` defines

```
TCollectionNotification = (cnAdded, cnExtracting, cnDeleting);
```

and `System.Generics.Collections` defines

```
TCollectionNotification = (cnAdded, cnRemoved, cnExtracted);
```

Almost certainly you have `Generics.Collections` declared *before* `Classes` in your `uses` clause and the compiler is resolving the undesired version of `TCollectionNotification`.

To fix it, either reorganize your `uses` clauses so that `Generics.Collections` comes after `Classes` **or** use a fully qualified type name, ie :

```
  procedure Notify(const Value: TSomeClass;
    Action: Generics.Collections.TCollectionNotification); override;
```

---

The lesson with a `differs from previous declaration` error is to methodically check your types.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CLICK</kbd> on the type identifier will take you to the definition of the type the compiler is using.

Comment: Perfect! I made both things: reorganized the `uses` clause **AND** put the fully qualified name. +1 and accepted

Comment: In RAD Studio 10.4 ` TCollectionNotification = (cnAdding, cnAdded, cnExtracting, cnExtracted, cnDeleting, cnRemoved);`