# Cannot override TCollection.Notify: Declaration of Notify differs from previous declaration

Tags: delphi, tcollection

Note: The title of [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308109/how-to-inherit-generic-virtual-method) is different which prevents it from identifying as the matching one.

**System.Classes**

```
TCollection = class(TPersistent)
protected
  procedure Notify(Item: TCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification); virtual;
end;
```

**MyUnit**

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, DB, System.Generics.Collections;

TTextDisplayLineInfos = class(TCollection)
protected
  procedure Notify(Item: TCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification); override; //Here "[dcc32 Error] MyUnit.pas(85): E2037 Declaration of 'Notify' differs from previous declaration"
end;

implementation

procedure TTextDisplayLineInfos.Notify(Item: TCollectionItem;
  Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited; //Here "[dcc32 Error] MyUnit.pas(475): E2008 Incompatible types"
  //..............
end;
```

The signature of Notify method has been taken by copy-paste, so there couldn't be any errors;

**Error**

In interface section:

> [dcc32 Error] MyUnit.pas(85): E2037 Declaration of 'Notify' differs from previous declaration

In implementation section:

> [dcc32 Error] MyUnit.pas(475): E2008 Incompatible types

**Question**

Whai is wrong?

Comment: Right-click on the erroneous declaration. The top item in the context menu that shows up should be something like "Find Declaration". Click that and find the "previous" declaration and see if it differs. The reason could be that your declaration in the interface and implementation section don't match, or that there is another class TCollection closer in scope than the TCollection you want to extend, or a different declaration of TCollectionNotification, or... or...

Comment: Then there must be a TCollection inbetween. Find the declaration of TCollection and see if it is the one you expect it to be. Also, clear your project and see if there are different files with the same name (i.e. a different version of your unit code somewhere, being picked up) in a directory in the search path. I use the free [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) for such a search. It is extremely fast (usually immediate result). Also check if there is a different TCollectionNotification somewhere in scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inherit generic virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308109/how-to-inherit-generic-virtual-method)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately Delphi declares `TCollectionNotification` twice: one resides in *System.Classes* and another one in *System.Generics.Collections*.

To workaround this issue, move *System.Generics.Collections* before *System.Classes* in your uses clause, or qualify it as `System.Classes.TCollectionNotification`).

Comment: Aha! As I though, a different TCollectionNotification, changing the signature of Notify.

Comment: Corresponding bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19791