# dirtest example code included in Delphi Rio help. Is there something obvious I have omitted?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have populated a form with required components and pasted the example code into a buttonclick event.

I have added the TStringDynArrayarray and TSearchOption type declarations but I get compilation errors as shown below.

```
unit dirtest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, System.Types, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs, IOUtils, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TStringDynArray = Array of String;
  TSearchOption = (soTopDirectoryOnly, soAllDirectories);
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    mmResults: TMemo;
    cbIncludeDirectories: TCheckBox;
    cbIncludeFiles: TCheckBox;
    cbDoRecursive: TCheckBox;
    edtPath: TEdit;
    edtFileMask: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  I: Integer;
  LSearchOption: TSearchOption;
begin
  { Select the search option }
  if cbDoRecursive.Checked then
    LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soAllDirectories
  else
    LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;

  try
    { For all entries use GetFileSystemEntries method }
    if cbIncludeDirectories.Checked and cbIncludeFiles.Checked then
      LList := TDirectory.GetFileSystemEntries(edtPath.Text, LSearchOption, nil;

    { For directories use GetDirectories method }
    if cbIncludeDirectories.Checked and not cbIncludeFiles.Checked then
      LList := TDirectory.GetDirectories(edtPath.Text, edtFileMask.Text,
        LSearchOption);

    { For files use GetFiles method }
    if not cbIncludeDirectories.Checked and cbIncludeFiles.Checked then
      LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(edtPath.Text, edtFileMask.Text,
        LSearchOption);
  except
    { Catch the possible exceptions }
    MessageDlg('Incorrect path or search mask', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  { Populate the memo with the results }
  mmResults.Clear;

  for I := 0 to Length(LList) - 1 do
    mmResults.Lines.Add(LList[I]);
end;

end.
```

The errors I get are thus...

[dcc32 Error] dirtest.pas(51): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetFileSystemEntries' that can be called with these arguments
[dcc32 Error] dirtest.pas(56): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetDirectories' that can be called with these arguments
[dcc32 Error] dirtest.pas(61): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetFiles' that can be called with these arguments

Can you see what's going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type declaration introduces **new** types for `TStringDynArray` and `TSearchOption` while functions expect types declared in in-built units ( `TStringDynArray = TArray<string>;` from `System.Types` and `TSearchOption` from IOUtils )

So just remove own type description

Comment: Good lord, the amount of time I spent going around in circles on this. Wish I had asked yesterday! Thank you MBo!

Comment: And watch out, because the RTL itself [steps on its own toes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37308109/327083) from time to time.